# Kafka broker performance issue with timeoutexception

Tags: apache-kafka

We have below Kafka setup

```
Partition - 10
Replication - 3
fetch.max.byte at broker - 32MB

Producer
max.block.ms =- 5min
request.timeout.mm - 5min
retries - 4

Consumer
No custom config

Message size - 1kb
```

With this setup we face following issue:

1. When producer puts huge load of message, sometimes producer throws an exception saying Batch Expired as linger time has been passed. I understand that this exception comes when producer puts faster than consumer can consume, but is there any config which I can set which prevents this exception and wait until consumer is able to consume. As this is a streaming data and the app just cannot lose any message and also the order is important.
2. The other problem i see is when Producer publishes even 10-15 messages, that message reaches consumer after around 6 seconds. and this delay keeps increasing if the number of messages are large. I checked Broker logs and observed that as soon as it reached broker the consumer is able to consume it. But it reaches to the broker after 5-6 seconds. Here the load is not much still it takes 6 seconds.
   How should I improve the performance.
   My app receives data from upstream and publish to kafka topic 1. 
   From this kafka topic1 another app consumes and aggregate data based on a key and publishes to another kafka topic 2

Topic 1 is producer for topic2 so as per our analysis topic publishing is fine but consumption from topic1 has a delay. 
And we think its because of the broker.

Answer (score 0):

If you saw exceptions that `linger.ms` time had been exceeded, it means that the batch of messages has been in send buffer for more than `linger.ms`. You can set `linger.ms` to zero have the producer send messages to broker immediately.

Based on your description, the delay happens on the producing side. Other than setting `linger.ms` to zero, tweaking the following settings may help to reduce the producing latency:

```
acks= 1   # Leader will write the record to its local log but will
          # respond without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers.

batch.size # reduce the batch size so that the producer do not wait for 
           # a larger batch size

delivery.timeout.ms # this is available since Kafka 2.1, and allows you 
                    # specify clearly on delivery timeout

max.in.flight.requests.per.connection # increase # of inflight request can 
                                      # help to improve throughput
```

Comment: This exception occurs when producer sends at a faster rate, if we set linger time to 0 and it sends message immediately without waiting, wont it further enhance the problem as now the producer will send it even faster rate. Also regarding the max in flight request our throughput seems to be fine our problem is latency

Comment: Have you checked if your program has frequent long gc pause?  Any network connective issue?

Comment: No network issue, how can i check gc pauses any specific log to check? My app is running with 5gb mem and i see this issue even with a small load of messages (5-10)

Comment: can you provide more context on what your application do?  if you enable gc logging   using `-verbosegc -Xloggc:$log_file_path`,  you can check the gc logs to see if there is any long pause gc.

Comment: Updated the question for more details. Also can you let us know if setting linger time yo 0 will worsen the problem or  an resolve it